# SQL Query calculating two additional columns

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, window-functions

I have a table which gets populated daily with database size. I need to modify the query where I can calculate daily growth and weekly growth.

```
select * from sys.dbsize 
where SNAP_TIME > sysdate -3
order by SNAP_TIME
```

Current Output

[image]

I would like to add two additional columns which would be
Daily Growth (DB_SIZE sysdate - DB_SIZE (sysdate -1))
Weekly Growth (DB_SIZE sysdate - DB_SIZE (sysdate -7))

Need some help constructing the SQL for those two additional columns. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `LAG` analytic function to calculate daily growth and correlated subquery (within the `SELECT` statement) for weekly growth.

For example:

```
SQL> with dbsize (snap_time, db_size) as
  2    (select sysdate - 8, 100 from dual union all
  3     select sysdate - 7, 110 from dual union all
  4     select sysdate - 6, 105 from dual union all
  5     select sysdate - 5, 120 from dual union all
  6     select sysdate - 4, 130 from dual union all
  7     select sysdate - 3, 130 from dual union all
  8     select sysdate - 2, 142 from dual union all
  9     select sysdate - 1, 144 from dual union all
 10     select sysdate - 0, 150 from dual
 11    )
 12  select
 13    a.snap_time,
 14    a.db_size,
 15    a.db_size - lag(a.db_size) over (order by a.snap_time) daily_growth,
 16    --
 17    db_size - (select db_size from dbsize b
 18               where trunc(b.snap_time) = trunc(a.snap_time) - 7
 19              ) weekly_growth
 20  from dbsize a
 21  order by a.snap_time;

SNAP_TIME              DB_SIZE DAILY_GROWTH WEEKLY_GROWTH
------------------- ---------- ------------ -------------
24.08.2020 21:52:20        100
25.08.2020 21:52:20        110           10
26.08.2020 21:52:20        105           -5
27.08.2020 21:52:20        120           15
28.08.2020 21:52:20        130           10
29.08.2020 21:52:20        130            0
30.08.2020 21:52:20        142           12
31.08.2020 21:52:20        144            2            44
01.09.2020 21:52:20        150            6            40

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, how to I update the dummy values for  db_size which you have provided with the actual values?

Comment: Lines #1 - 11 are sample data; you already have that in your table. Query you might need begins at line #12.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `lag()` for both columns:

```
select s.*,
       (dbsize - dbsize_1) as daily_growth,
       (dbsize - dbsize_7) as weekly_growth
from (select s.*,
             lag(dbsize) over (order by snap_time) as dbsize_1,
             lag(dbsize, 7) over (order by snap_time) as dbsize_7
      from sys.dbsize 
     ) s
where SNAP_TIME > sysdate -3
order by SNAP_TIME;
```

If you don't have a snapshot each day, you can handle this with a window frame:

```
select s.*,
       (dbsize - dbsize_1) as daily_growth,
       (dbsize - dbsize_7) as weekly_growth
from (select s.*,
             max(dbsize) over (order by trunc(snap_time) range between interval '1' day preceding and interval '1' second preceding) as dbsize_1,
             lag(dbsize, 7) over (order by trunc(snap_time) range between '7' day preceding and interval '6 1' day to hour) as dbsize_7
      from sys.dbsize 
     ) s
where SNAP_TIME > sysdate - 3
order by SNAP_TIME;
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is always is one record per day, you can use `lag()`:

```
select 
    snap_time
    db_size,
    db_size - lag(db_size, 1) over(order by snap_time) daily_growth,
    db_size - lag(db_size, 7) over(order by snap_time) weekly_growth
from sys.db.size
order by snap_time
```

This actually looks 1 row back and 7 rows back. If there are missing dates, or multiple records per day, then you could average the snap size by day, and use a window range in the window function:

```
select 
    trunc(snap_time) snap_day,
    avg(db_size) avg_db_size,
    avg(db_size) - avg(db_size) over(
        order by trunc(snap_time)
        range between interval '1' day preceding and interval '1' day preceding
    ) daily_growth,
    avg(db_size) - avg(db_size) over(
        order by trunc(snap_time)
        range between interval '7' day preceding and interval '7' day preceding
    ) weekly_growth
from sys.db.size
group by trunc(snap_time)
order by trunc(snap_time)
```

If you want the results for the last 3 days only, you can turn any of the two above queries to subqueries, and filter in the outer query:

```
select *
from ( ... ) t
where snap_time > sysdate - 3 -- or: snap_day > trunc(sysdate) - 3
```